# finding a permutation h of {0,...,n-1} such that h_i+a_i becomes increasing

Tags: algorithm, adhoc

An array `a` of n integers between 0 and n-1 is given.
The answer is a permutation of (0,...,n-1) such that:

```
a_0 + h_0 <= a_1 + h_1 <= ... <= a_n-1 + h_n-1 <= n-1
```

`n <= 60` and the answer is unique.

For example if `a` is (0,2,4,2,0) the answer (`h`) is uniquely determined(as the problem promised):

h = (3,1,0,2,4)

Comment: This can't hold if for example `a = (1,1,1,...,1)` since we must have `a_i + h_i > = 1 + (n - 1) > n - 1` for some value `i`. Could you restate the question with stricter conditions on `a` and indicate what you mean when you say "The answer is"?

Comment: is `h` the resulting permutation?

Comment: @bossylobster the unique answer is a part of problem statement, you should solve it assuming that, maybe `a` is too specific.

Comment: @amit yes, h is the permutation of (0,...,n-1).

Comment: @a-z just because the answer is unique does not mean that each entry of `a` is unique. Since you were able to use the term permutation correctly in the second sentence, you would have been better off saying `a` was a permutation. As for "the answer", you refer to `h` but never explicitly say `h` is the answer.